# Can method operating on array of class object use array methods?

Tags: python, arrays, class, methods

I'm new here, and new in Python. I had some C/C++ in colleague. I'm doing course from udemy and I'm wonderig if there is some better idea of the issiue of finding element of an array of class object based on one value. The course task was to find "the oldest cat". Solution there is just using no Lists/arrays but I wanna know how to operate on arrays of objects and if there is better option than my static method getoldest, becouse for me it seems like I'm trying to "cheat" python.

```
    class Cat:

    def getoldest(Cat=[]):
        age_table=[]
        for one in Cat:
            age_table.append(one.age)         
        return Cat[age_table.index(max(age_table))]

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age


# 1 Instantiate the Cat object with few cats
kotki3=[]
kotki3.append(Cat("zimka", 5))
kotki3.append(Cat("korek", 9))
kotki3.append(Cat("oczko", 10))
kotki3.append(Cat("kotek", 1))
kotki3.append(Cat("edward", 4))

# 2 Create a function that finds the oldest cat

oldest = Cat.getoldest(kotki3)

# 3 Print out: "The oldest cat is x years old.". x will be the oldest cat age by using the function in #2

print(f'The oldest cat is {oldest.name} and it\'s {oldest.age} years old')
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: A more straightforward way would be to use `max()` on the list of cat objects: `oldest = max(kotki3, key=lambda x: x.age)`

Comment: Terminology notes: that is a list, not an array. Note, you don't have "class objects" inside your list, class objects would be the *classes themselves* (which are first-class objects in Python, pretty much everything is an object in Python). You have instances of your class in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this example could help you see a better way of doing that

```py
class Cat:

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def get_details(self):
        return self.name, self.age


cats = [Cat("zimka", 5),
         Cat("oczko", 10),
         Cat("kotek", 1),
         Cat("edward", 4) ]

results = []
for cat in cats:
    (name, age) = cat.get_details()
    results.append((name,age))
print(sorted(results, key = lambda x: -x[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @classmethod thus the function will be static and will get the class as a first argument default, as well the _Instances variable made static here.

When a new Cat is instantiated it will be added to the _Instances list.

```
class Cat:
    _Instances=[]

    @classmethod
    def getoldest(cls):
        _Instance = max(cls._Instances,key=lambda Instance: Instance.age)
        return ("Oldest {} is {}, and {} years old.".format(cls.__name__,_Instance.name,_Instance.age))

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.__class__._Instances.append(self)

Cat("a",1)
Cat("b",2)
Cat("c",3)
Cat("d",4)
print(Cat.getoldest())
```